# provide a style for textblock in the gridview

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-8

I have a gridview and there're many gridviewitems in it, every gridviewitem contains some textblock, could I specify a style for all of the textblock at once? Not specify the style one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to leverage the [object resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview) and name it implicitly. Something like;

```
<GridView>
  <GridView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
       <!-- Etc, etc, etc -->
    </Style>
  </GridView.Resources>
</GridView>
```